# HOWTO handle 404 exceptions globally using Spring MVC configured using Java based Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I am building a Spring 4 MVC app. And it is completely configured using Java Annotations. There is no `web.xml`. The app is configured by using instance of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like so,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.*"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/properties/application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

and

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
...
}
```

I am now trying to add a global/catch-all exception handler for 404 pages i.e. `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` but no success. Below are some of the ways I tried.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ModelAndView handleException (NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            return mav;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ModelAndView handleExceptiond (NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            return mav;
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {

    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
    public void handlesdConflict() {
    }

}
```

None of these methods get executed. I am at a loss as to how to handle this. I do not want to use `web.xml` becasue then I would have to create one just for this.

Comment: I don't know why they didn't make the `DispatcherServlet` visible through some `protected` method, but the custom solution seems good.

Comment: Why dont you just override just createDispatcherServlet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[By default, the `DispatcherServlet` does not throw a `NoHandlerFoundException`.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound-boolean-) You need to enable that.

The `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` should let you override how the `DispatcherServlet` is created. Do that and call

```
DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = ...; // might get it from super implementation
dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios for the response. But I dont seem to be able to get the `dispatcherServlet` in `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

Comment: @Chantz Override the `registerDispatcherServlet`. Look at the implementation of the super type to get an idea of what to do.

Comment: One year later... Is there a simpler way of doing this? I usually don't override registerDispatcherServlet in my Initializer so I find this method too verbose. All those lines rewritten just to add one line.

Comment: @Link Looking at the source, it doesn't look like they've changed it.

Comment: But you can override createDispatcherServlet by adding one more line to it as I mentioned down

Answer (score 7):

Enable DispatcherServlet throw a NoHandlerFoundException through web.xml configuartion.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead overriding `registerDispatcherServlet` one can override the `createDispatcherServlet` method as follows.

```
@Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
        DispatcherServlet ds = new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        ds.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem with the following entry in my application.yml

```
 server.error.whitelabel.enabled: false
 spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
```

and the following ControllerExceptionHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String processMethodNotSupportedException(Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
    return "error";
}

}
```

and last but not least i added a template "/html/error.html"

Comment: After SpringBoot version 2.0, using `spring.mvc.throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound: true`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the above post by @Ysak (reputation<50), however I can confirm that this method does work with the setup described by the OP.

I will add that from another guide I also had the DefaultServletHandling configured in my WebConfig to fix a separate issue, as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.acme.tat.controllers")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
...
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
}

}
```

With this set to enable, there is no Exception thrown.  Once I removed this line and set up manual resourceHandlers everything worked as expected.

It took me around 2.5 hours to set up 404 redirecting because of this simple one line method.